# How many ways are there of getting stdin input in perl?

Tags: perl

I have been learning perl, and find the motto interesting. It says there are multiple ways of doing anything. I know that you can use `print` and `say` to output stuff, but I haven't found any other way to read input than to use a predefined file pointer-like thing.

Are there any other ways?

Comment: why the downvote? Me not including exactly how to read from a file, which is pretty irrelevant?

Comment: `echo` is not a Perl function.

Comment: See [read](http://p3rl.org/read), [sysread](http://p3rl.org/sysread), [readline](http://p3rl.org/readline), `<>`, `<<>>`, and maybe more.

Comment: @choroba it is if you `use feature ':5.10'`

Comment: @choroba why not make that an answer?

Comment: 5.10 introduces [say](http://p3rl.org/say), not `echo`.

Comment: Because of "maybe" :-)

Comment: On the fun side - Me personally love the _sperm (kite) operator_ :-) `~~<>`  From the [perlsecret](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlsecret#Kite): _This operator is actually a combination of the inchworm and the diamond operator. It provides scalar context to the readline() builtin, thus returning a single line of input._ example: `@triplets = ( ~~<>, ~~<>, ~~<> );    # three sperms in a single egg?`

Comment: @choroba In case of "maybe" - you can (shloud?) write an answer and change it to [community wiki answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) - so anybody can extend it and make it perfect for the all future readers. But yes, I understand - no reputation gain = no motivation for such answers...

Comment: @choroba oh. ok. remembered wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is too broad.

There are many different ways to read from a handle:

- `<>`/`readline` (with `$/ = $line_ending;`)
- `<>`/`readline` (with `$/ = undef;`)
- `<>`/`readline` (with `$/ = \$block_size;`)
- `<>`/`readline` (with `$/ = "";`)
- `getc`
- `read`
- `sysread`
- ...

Then there are tools to work with terminals.

- Term::ReadKey
- Term::ReadLine
- Curses
- ...

Also, handles can be represented in multiple ways.

- A reference to an IO value (e.g. `*STDIN{IO}`)
- A glob containing an IO value (e.g. `*STDIN`)
- A ref to a glob containing an IO value (e.g. `\*STDIN`)
- The name of a glob containing an IO value (e.g. `'STDIN'`)
- An IO::Handle object

In one-liners, `-n`, `-p`, `-l`, `-0`, `-F`, `-a` and `-C` all have some connection to STDIN.

...

Answer (score 1):

I know you are asking about standard input, but the idea underlying your question could use some clarification. I'll eventually get there, but first lets think about the foundation of the question.

Perl has a motto "There's More Than One Way To Do It" (TIMTOWTDI), but that's really thinking about the path to a particular outcome rather than a prescription that every low-level thing has redundancy or duplication.

Some things have apparent redundancy because the task shows up in different ways and sometimes there is a particular case that is so common that it has its own shortcut. It's these particular uses that lead to the overlap, not that every primitive must have an alternative.

Consider, for example, the `stat` function, which returns a list of things we know about a file (inode, whatever). One of those is the last modification time (if that makes sense on your filesystem).

```
my $mtime = (stat $file)[9];
```

You could get the modification times for two files and compare them, or you could use the modification time to check the age of a file:

```
if( $mtime > (time-86400) ) { say "File is over a day old" }
```

But, Perl with its sysadmin and reporting routes know that this task is a common one, so there's also the `-M` file test operator to return the file age in days since the start of the program:

```
if( -M $file > 1 ) { say "File is over a day old" }
```

If that's a task you do a lot, perhaps because you rotate log files, clean out directories, or whatever, this shorted, more tailored version is handy (if you can remember the sign of the value, since the past is positive).

Wrapped up in this idea is the "topic", which Perl calls `$_`, which some people really, really hate because you have to remember which things operate on the topic. Instead of repeating the thing you want to use, you put it in `$_` so it's the default thing:

```
$_ = 'some_file'
if( -M > 1 ) { say "$_ is over a day old" }
```

or with postfix notation:

```
say "$_ is over a day old" if -M > 1;
```

or as a one-liner, where brevity is a virtue (to a certain extent):

```
$ ls | perl -lne 'print if -M > 1'
```

So now consider standard input. We could have a language with only `sysread` to get raw octets from disk. We'd have to handle all sorts of other things, such as constructing lines, knowing when to stop, decoding the data, and so on. It's so tedious that I'm not even going to type out the example. But, more commonly, we want to read lines of text, so there's the `readline` which does all that work for us:

```
open my $fh, ...;
while( readline($fh) ) { ... }
```

There's also a synonym for that, as the diamond operator:

```
while( <$fh> ) { ... }
```

If you wanted standard input, a frequent task, you use the pre-defined filehandle name for that:

```
while( <STDIN> ) { ... }
```

But, reading from standard input is so common that it's also the default filehandle for `<>` when used in a `while` like this:

```
while( <> ) { ... }
```

Well, almost. It's really the `ARGV` filehandle that's the default, which then reads standard input if you supplied no arguments to the program. The `ARGV` is another level of shortcut that reads many files for you and presents them as if there were the same input source. That it handles standard input if the absence of an explicit source is simply another nod to what we are likely to want to do.

Larry as a linguist was probably at least aware of Zipf's *Human Behavior and the Principle of Least Effort". Zipf develops the analogy of a worker's tool bench where the most often used tools are closest to the worker, then pivots to human language where the most often expressed ideas have the shortest words (which are specialized tools). That `-M` is an oftenly expressed idea, even though you can do the same thing with idea-agnostic primitives. And, Larry often spoke of Huffman coding, the idea that in representing (e.g. compressing) repeated things, the most frequently appearing things get the shortest codes. In Larry's programming language, the most frequent tasks should have the shortest paths.

As such, Perl has the general ways of doing things, but then recognizes that there are some particular, more specialized tasks that are common enough that they should get their own syntax or special behavior. You can choose the level of generality based on what your problem demands.

Perl's philosophy is the flip side of the "pythonic" idea from Python where two people doing the same job should roughly come up with the same code using the same primitives used in the same way. There is one preferred way to do things. This can be valuable because the programmer doesn't need to remember an excessively long list of programming things to get the job done, even if common ideas do not have bespoke constructs. A team of programmers should have fewer style and flavor differences, which has its advantages.

And, not for nothing, segments of the Perl community lean toward the idea of "pythonic" too with their preferred modules and idioms. This leads to TIMTOWTDIBSCINABTE (there is more than one way to to it, but sometimes consistency is not a bad thing either) or TIMTOWTDIBMOTAW (there is more than one way to to it, but most of them are wrong).